# Can't get value from web form for double value in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core

Have this class:

```
public class ClientViewModel
{
    public long PKID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string DT_RowId { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

And this code for razor view:

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Clients" asp-action="Edit">
    <input asp-for="PKID" type="hidden" />

    <div class="portlet-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label asp-for="Name">Name:</label>
                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" placeholder="Name" asp-for="Name">
                <span class="help-block has-error" asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row physical-row default-row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label class="control-label">Unit</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Unit, new {placeholder = "Unit", id = "physicalLocationUnit", @class = "form-control input-sm"})
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Street</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Street, new {placeholder = "PhysicalAddress", id = "physicalLocation", onfocus = "physicalinitialize()", @class = "form-control input-sm"})
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 postcode-box">
                        <label class="control-label">Post Code</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text"
                                   tabindex="-1"
                                   class="form-control input-sm" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 lattitude-box">
                        <label class="control-label" asp-for="Latitude">Latitude</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text"
                                   tabindex="-1"
                                   class="form-control input-sm" asp-for="Latitude" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 longitude-box">
                        <label class="control-label" asp-for="Longitude">Longitude</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text"
                                   tabindex="-1"
                                   class="form-control input-sm" asp-for="Longitude" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-6">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn green">Save</button>
                        <a asp-controller="Clients" asp-action="WorkManage" asp-route-id="@Model.PKID" class="btn green">Add Work</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In Longitude and Latitude has value for example `1.3` and `2.45` but when i try to call controller method i have just `0` value in this variables. Where i was wrong? 
Cheers!

Comment: When Longitude and Latitude has value for example `1,3` and `2,45` it works. But when js validator don't get possible to save this, because want to see `1.3` and `2.45`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is not working with a period, is that the default `CultureInfo` on your server accepts only commas as decimal separators.

You might want to try setting the default culture to one that expects periods as decimal separators.

You could do that in your `startup.cs`, like this :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, FinOsDbContext context)
{
    app.UseRequestLocalization();

    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("*insert culture*");
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("*insert culture*");
}
```

If you always intend to use a period as decimal separator, regardless of the culture's default, you could specify which decimal separator the culture should use like so :

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = new CultureInfo("*insert culture*");
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = customCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

Comment: Asp.Net has some very extensive culture support. you can even specify multiple supported cultures and use localization per request (http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/setting-thread-culture-aspnet5/)

Comment: Try to insert your code in startup.cs but hase error because didn't see this method `CurrentUICulture`. Are you sure that for .net core?

Comment: should have been `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentculture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`. since you are using .net core, there is no global.asax either, so that is wrong too

Comment: Your solution help me, just need to some change code for .net core
Like this: 
`var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");

            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;`